# WCF Authentication Flow

Tags: asp.net, wcf, security, authentication, wshttpbinding

I'm calling a WCF service from an ASP.NET application. From this, I am accessing a WCF service using WSHTTPBinding. I can get the current user from `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`. I want to be able to pass this to WCF (not using a custome header - *surely* there is a proper way to do this.) It must be the identity in `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` and not `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`, as this service may be consumed from ASP.nET applications that use Forms or Windows authentication. From what I understand, it should appear in `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name`. I have search for ages to try to find the answer to this but have not yet found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Username Authentication :)
http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2010/03/22/a-simple-wcf-service-with-username-password-authentication-the-things-they-don-t-tell-you/

Comment: Not exactly what I was after but only answer!